# How to deploy ASP.net web application

Tags: vb.net, deployment

I'm new to ASP.Net and have been told to Deploy my project to a specific network location.

After extensive research before I did anything, including here, I have found that similar terms like "Deployment Package" "Package" "Install Package" "Publish" "Deploy" all seem to mean the same thing, contextually speaking making my task that much more difficult.

I was told to use the Publish command from the Build menu and point to a shared network folder, which I did but then thought that may have been wrong because things didn't look right in the folder.

I was expecting an application or executable object but found none. Instead I found, basically compiled versions of my web site pages along with more folders.

So, back to the internet and I found more things like MSBuild and editing of the project file after unloading it to add before and after Tasks and more questions concerning how is it to be accessed; should it run from the folder where it resides or should it be installed and then run. Now this really made me think I did something wrong.

Is there something I need to do NOW, after publishing the web application or is just lack of experience or did I truly do it wrong?

Frankly, I'm thoroughly confused at this point.

Red.

Comment: An ASP.net web application needs to be published to a web server to run. It won't just run out of any random file directory on your computer as far as I know. IIS is the standard (only?) webserver for this. Once you know what folder IIS is looking into for content, then you use the publish option that you tried first and have it publish to that folder.

Comment: If they are asking you to deploy it to a network location, it sounds like they just want you to copy the files to that location. In VS, Build -> Publish, choose "File System" as the publish method. Then change the "Target location" to your directory path.

Comment: Deploying from VS is the easiest way. MsBuild can be used if you need to script the build process. You can then use [WebDeploy](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy) to copy the files to the IIS server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx for deploying a Web Project Using One-Click Publish in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are deploying a web application, this kind of applications dont have an executable, this deploy process generates a list of files (some dlls) that the web server understands